# How to rename geometry main group inputs so they reflect in the dopesheet as well?

Tags: dopesheet, geometry-nodes

I am trying to figure out how to rename the properties in the dopesheet to match that of the main inputs of the main geometry group but there seems to be no user-friendly way to do this? Am i missing something? It can get confusing with so many inputs to animate. In this example `input_12` is the `_asdf` named input but in the dopesheet it only shows `input_12` instead of `_asdf`

[image]

Comment: The dopesheet show the data path, not the name.

Comment: @XY yes. so how do i change the name in the dopesheet?

Comment: It's currently not possible (AFAIK) but I hope it will change at some point.

Comment: @Gorgious oh ok. thank you, at least now i know why i couldn't find anything XD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Gorgious has mentioned this is currently not possible. you can use group channels though to help organize the dopesheet